# How do i plot a graph for width vs height of the slits from an image

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, fitting, image-processing, regions

[image]

I need to calculate the width of the slits along the length of each slits. I am new to image processing in mathematica and I need to plot a graph showing how the width changes along the length.

I have also converted and deleted the noises. Now I have an image showing only edges. Could anyone please help to get to know the thickness of two beams along its length. [image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please, update your question with this information. Thanks!

Comment: Which parts of the image are the slits? The dark or the light parts? If you write a more detailed question, we can do a better job of trying to help you.

Comment: The rectangular beams or gray portion are the slits here. I need to calculate the thickness of the slits along the whole length. Then I need to plot as a graph showing how the thickness varies along its length

Comment: `EdgeDetect[img, 10]` should get you started. The slits seem to be of rather uniform width (24px light gray, 55px dark gray). At the top of the image automatic methods have more problems, so one can do better when including prior knowledge about the problem, like are the boundaries of the slits straight lines?

Answer (score 1):

`EdgeDetect[]` needed a bit of adjusting of the radius and threshold to accommodate the low signal to noise ratio in the upper part of the image.

This seems to work:

```
pic = ImageAdjust[
  ColorConvert[Import["NPx8s.jpg"], 
   "Grayscale"]];
Manipulate[edgepic = EdgeDetect[pic, {r1, r2}, t];
 HighlightImage[pic, edgepic], {{r1, 243}, 0, 600, 1}, {{r2, 2}, 0, 
  10, 1}, {{t, .07}, 0, .1}]
```

[image]

Since the lines are connected we can use `MorphologicalComponents[]` to get the coordinates of the different lines.

```
line1pts = Position[MorphologicalComponents[edgepic], 1];
line2pts = Position[MorphologicalComponents[edgepic], 2];
```

etc..

And the distance between them is

```
dis12=MapThread[EuclideanDistance, {line1pts, line2pts}]
ListPlot[dis12]
```

[image]